# RDD size remains the same even after compressing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I use SparkListener to monitor the cached RDDs' sizes. However, I notice that no matter what I do, the RDDs' size always remain the same. I did the following things to compress the RDDs.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
conf.set("spark.rdd.compress","true")
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.....
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
....
myrdd.persist(MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Even, if I remove the second and third lines shown above, Spark listener shows the same size of the RDD, which means that setting **`spark.rdd.compress`** to true and enabling kryo serialization had no effect (OK kryo is only for serialization, but **`spark.rdd.compress`** at least could have done the trick). What mistake could I be doing?

Note that my RDD is of type (Long, String). Could that be the reason? I mean, could it be that Spark doesn't compress RDDs of this type, especially when strings are short in size?

P.S: I am using Spark 1.6

Comment: Do you set the properties before creating the `SparkContext`?

Comment: Yes, I set them before creating the SparkContext.

Comment: were able to identify issue and resolve?