# spark.rdd.compress and its effect for saving tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Coming from questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112007/rdd-size-remains-the-same-even-after-compressing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261987/when-to-use-kryo-serialization-in-spark/40263340) one I asked myself if `spark.rdd.compress` has also an effect when I save a dataframe, which is partitioned on RDD-level, to a (for example) parquet-table.
Or maybe in other words: Does `spark.rdd.compress` also compress the table I create when I use `dataframe.write.saveAsTable(...)`?

Taken from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#overriding-configuration-directory), spark.rdd.compress does the following:

> Whether to compress serialized RDD partitions (e.g. for
>   StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER in Java and Scala or
>   StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY in Python). **Can save substantial space at the
>   cost of some extra CPU time**. Compression will use
>   spark.io.compression.codec.

So, additionally, if such compression works, will it also cost additional CPU to retrieve data again from such a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does spark.rdd.compress also compress the table I create when I use dataframe.write.saveAsTable(...)

It won't, and neither it will for RDD sinks.

As stated in the documentation you quote, it is applicable only for serialized (`_SER`) caching. It has nothing to do with external storage.